# Firefox: parent does not feel dynamic content width

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-float

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vZkzR/1/)

If the adjacent element of a parent floating, the parent does not feel the width of the element, if it is dynamic. In chrome and opera works fine.

```
<div class="b-wrap">
    <div class="b-content">
        <div class="b-rect-left"></div>
        <div class="b-rect-right"></div>
        <div class="b-child-cont">джигурдаололо</div>
    </div>
</div>

.b-wrap {
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
   float: left;
}

.b-content {
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.b-rect-left {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
   float: left;
    background-color: orange;
}

.b-rect-right {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
    background-color: green;
}

.b-child-cont {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox calculated the width of an element that contains floats differently from Chrome.  I don't know why.

However, what seems to be happening is the following.

The actual content in your snippet is in `b-child-cont`, a non-floated element. `b-child-cont` determines the width of `b-content` since the two other elements are (`b-rect-left` and `b-rect-right`) are floated and do not factor into determining the width of the content.  In turn, the  width of `b-content` sets the width of `b-wrap`, because `b-wrap` is floated and takes on the width of its child elements.

You as a designer and developer, need to allow some space for the two floated elements.  You can do this in many ways.  I will give two examples.

(1) Add left and right margins to `b-child-cont`:

```
.b-child-cont {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

(Note: I added a background color to show the extend of the element.) The 40px and 30px values are based on the widths of the left and right square elements respectively.

(2) You can also specify a with to the parent element containing the floats:

```
.b-child-cont {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}
.b-content {
    width: 30em;
}
```

In this case, I set the with of `b-content` to 30em (you can adjust this accordingly) and I centered the text in `b-child-cont`.

You have come across a cross-browser discrepancy in how the CSS box model is calculated.  Once you are aware of it, you need to design around it, but that is not too hard to do.

Fiddle Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/dzK73

Comment: Thanks) Need to add `@-moz-document url-prefix()` for margin.

Comment: Your welcome, glad to help.  Just curious, why do you need the prefix?

Comment: In Opera and Chrome this margin is not required.

Comment: The CSS works the same in all browsers, so you don't have to make it browser specific, an added bonus.  Run the fiddle in Chrome, Opera, FF, and IE; you see the same thing.

Comment: [Chrome](https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/2255752/320749/c4d14b1e-9964-11e2-9aa9-a159130f6ed7.PNG). In opera is normal.

Comment: Good catch, which version of Chrome? I tested the fiddle in Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43 m.

Comment: Previous version,  25.0.1364.172 m

Comment: Wow, must be a Chrome bug! In that case, the prefix makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this firefox exception

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.b-wrap{width:175px;}
}
```

Comment: This is not a good fix because the 175px value is specific to that text and that font-size.  `b-wrap` is meant to be floated so the fixed width needs be set on `b-content` if it is to be set at all.